# AHow to separate menu strip from the slider in kona theme of Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on this Wordpress website in which Kona theme is used. Someone already did some changes in the original theme after the installation. Hence, now I am having this issue where my menu bar is appearing on the slider itself in desktop mode. In mobile/tablet mode, it is working okay. However, desktop mode shows the menu like this as shown in the image below. I am not much experienced in WordPress, hence, I am finding it hard to separate the menu strip and slider and make it responsive.
Can someone guide me what can I do in this regard?
[This is the image. Please click on the link to see the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R68bH.jpg)

Edit: Here's the website link --> https://www.pinsandpearls.com/

Comment: surly this is the issue related to CSS code written for desktop or large screen size devices. you need to check it using console inspectopr.

Comment: please give us the website link, we could help you better

Comment: @ThomasLIBERATO Here is the website link: https://www.pinsandpearls.com/

Answer (score 0):

That's for the link. In your CSS you have something like this:

```
#header {
    z-index: 1501;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Instead, try it:

```
#header {
    z-index: 1501;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but it didn't work.

Comment: No you did'nt replace position attribute value by "relative"